# Где можно посмотреть реализацию ключевых слов C++?

Tags: c++, компиляция, gcc, реализация, implementation

Где можно посмотреть реализацию ключевых слов C++? Например, как реализован `static_assert` в gcc?

Comment: в сорцах gcc - https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc Но лучше сформулируйте вопрос, может Вам книгу дракона почитать?

Comment: @KoVadim в какой директории? а лучше какой файл?

Comment: ¿Почему вы думаете, что реализация сосредоточена в какой-то одной папке или файле? Тот же `static_assert` требует выполнения в во время компиляции произвольных выражений и тянет за собой почти весь остальной язык. Неконтролируемый рост сложности языка привел к тому, что современные компиляторы тоже неконтролируемо разрослись.

Comment: @user7860670 интересен файл, где компилятор понимает, что перед ним `static_assert` или какое-то другое ключевое слово, а дальше по файлам уже сам отслежу, что делается

Comment: его можно найти по `parser_static_assert`

Comment: Здесь в комментариях очень умные люди уже подсказали Вам решение проблемы. я лишь оставлю здесь стать, которая разбирает методику решения такой проблемы:  https://habr.com/ru/post/576052/

Comment: @S.H. спасибо, интересно